# How can I set up GUFW so that only firefox connects to the internet

Tags: firewall, iptables, gufw

I only want http, https and DNS to be open.

I'm having troubles with setting up port ranges in the UFW GUI. How do I input configs into the feilds?

Basically, something along the lines of this, but in GUFW, as I'm trying to convert my Windows paranoid bro who hates the command line.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32768:61000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 --sport 32768:61000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 --sport 32768:61000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

And there has to be a logging system easily accessible to see any supposed intrusions.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the policy to first deny out going , then allow the ports you want.

```
gksu gufw
```

When you open gufw, it will look like this

[image: Default]

Enable the firewall by clicking the "Enabled" box

Deny Incoming and Outgoing.

Add a rule for the ports you wish to allow (80,443,53)

You can add a simple rule, and list your ports, it will look like this

[image: Rules]

Final result

[image: Final]

See the firweall section of [This guide](http://dangertux.wordpress.com/tutorials/ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-desktop-security-guide/#firewall) or [The ubuntu wiki GUFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw) for additional details.