# UFW Settings - Application Integration

Tags: firewall, ufw, gufw

I have installed the Ubuntu system, and deny both incoming and outgoing ports loosing internet access.

Now I want access only for my Firefox that I have installed separately from the Firefox website not the one from the repositories.

Now using Application Integration of UFW , I created a profile shown below:

```
[firefox]
title=firefox
description=firefox web browser
ports=80,443/tcp
```

and added 53 port to allowed list for DNS and then allowed Firefox app profile outgoing connection.

My final settings are shown below:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (full)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To Action From
-- ------ ----
53 ALLOW OUT Anywhere
80,443/tcp (firefox) ALLOW OUT Anywhere
53 ALLOW OUT Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (firefox (v6) ) ALLOW OUT Anywhere (v6)
```

Now, Firefox is able to access the internet, but all other applications are also able to access those open ports.

I want only Firefox to be able to access the Internet..

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90057/how-can-i-set-up-gufw-so-that-only-firefox-connects-to-the-internet). Can you try the solution there and see if it helps please?

Comment: Yes, this is similar to the link, but have already done those settings, problem is that my firefox profile for UFW is not working fine, It is made for firefox but allowing all application on port 80 and 443. Is is possible to tell ufw about the application with its path?

Comment: At this time there is no "application firewall" I would advise. My advise is for you to learn apparmor, I use an apparmor profile for all applications that are network aware.

Comment: Yep, I know there is no application firewall for linux, demanded from a long time by users coming from windows background, I am just trying to hit and try the feature of ufw application integration but no luck. And thank you for suggestion, I shall definitely try to learn apparmor.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)